# How to get the value of an input radio with 3 options in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, radio-button

First of all: I'd like to clarify that I did look for this question here, but the solutions were not working for me.

I'm just working on a small project for college.

I need to register the information of a new user, but I'm stuck at the radio button to get the user's gender and what type of user he is.

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registro</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>

       <label for="txtIdentificacion">Identifación</label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Número de identificación" id="txtIdentificacion" required>

       <label for="txtPrimerNombre">Primer Nombre</label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Primer Nombre" id="txtPrimerNombre"  required>

       <label for="txtSegundoNombre">Segundo Nombre</label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Segundo Nombre" id="txtSegundoNombre">

       <label for="txtPrimerApellido">Primer Apellido</label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Primer Apellido" id="txtPrimerApellido"  required>

       <label for="txtSegundoApellido">Segundo Apellido</label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Segundo Apellido" id="txtSegundoApellido" >

       <label for="txtNacionalidad">Nacionalidad</label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Nacionalidad" id="txtNacionalidad"  required>

       <label for="txtTipoIdentificacion">Tipo de Identificacion</label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Tipo de Identificacion" id="txtTipoIdentificacion"  required>

       <label for="datFechaNacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
       <input type="date" id="datFechaNacimiento"  required>

       <label for="">Género:</label>

       <label for="rbtFemenino">Femenino</label>
       <input type="radio" name="rbtGenero" value="Femenino" id="rbtFemenino" required >

       <label for="rbtMasculino">Masculino</label>
       <input type="radio" name="rbtGenero" value="Masculino" id="rbtMasculino" required >

       <label for="rbtIndefinido">Indefinido</label>
       <input type="radio" name="rbtGenero" value="Indefinido" id="rbtIndefinido" required>

       <label for="numNumeroTelefonico">Número Telefonico </label>
       <input type="number" placeholder="Sin guiones" id="numNumeroTelefonico"  required>

       <label for="txtNombreUsuario">Nombre de usuario</label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" id="txtNombreUsuario"  required>

       <label for="txtPassword">Contraseña</label>
       <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="txtPassword"  required>

       <label for="rbtTipoUsuario">Soy un instructor</label>
       <input type="radio" name="rbtTipoUsuario" value="Instructor" id="rbtInstructor">

       <label for="rbtTipoUsuario">Soy un cliente</label>
       <input type="radio" name="rbtTipoUsuario" value="Cliente" id="rbtCliente">

       <label for="numEmergencia">Número de emergencia</label>
       <input type="number" placeholder="Sin guiones" id="numEmergencia"  required>


       <button type="submit" class="btnRegistrar" id="btnRegistrar">Registrar</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
<script src="js/logicaNegociosUsuarios.js"></script>
<script src="js/logicaInterfazUsuarios.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
document.querySelector('#btnRegistrar').addEventListener('click', registrarNuevoUsuario);

registrarNuevoUsuario()



function registrarNuevoUsuario() {
    var aNuevoUsuario = [];
    var sIdentificacion = '';
    var sPrimerNombre = '';
    var sSegundoNombre = '';
    var sPrimerApellido = '';
    var sSegundoApellido = ''
    var sNacionalidad ='';
    var sTipoIdentificacion = '';
    var sFechaNacimiento = '';
    var sGender = '';
    var nNumeroTelefonico = 0;
    var sNombreUsuario = '';
    var sPassword = '';
    var nEdad = 0;
    var sTipoUsuario = '';
    var nEmergencia = '';

    sIdentificacion = document.querySelector('#txtIdentificacion').value;
    sPrimerNombre = document.querySelector('#txtPrimerNombre').value;
    sSegundoNombre = document.querySelector('#txtSegundoNombre').value;
    sPrimerApellido = document.querySelector('#txtPrimerApellido').value;
    sSegundoApellido = document.querySelector('#txtSegundoApellido').value;
    sNacionalidad = document.querySelector('#txtNacionalidad').value;
    sTipoIdentificacion = document.querySelector('#txtTipoIdentificacion').value;
    sFechaNacimiento = document.querySelector('#datFechaNacimiento').value;
    sGenero = document.querySelector('input[name="rbtGenero"]:checked') ?  document.querySelector('input[name="rbtGenero"]:checked').value : '';
    nNumeroTelefonico = document.querySelector('#numNumeroTelefonico').value;
    sNombreUsuario = document.querySelector('#txtNombreUsuario').value;
    sPassword = document.querySelector('#txtPassword').value;
    nEdad = calcularEdad();
    sTipoUsuario = document.querySelector('input[name="rbtTipoUsuario"]:checked') ? document.querySelector('input[name="rbtUserTipoUsuario"]:checked').value: '';
    nEmergencia = document.querySelector('#numEmergencia').value;

    aNuevoUsuario.push(sIdentificacion, sPrimerNombre, sSegundoNombre, sPrimerApellido, sSegundoApellido, sNacionalidad, sTipoIdentificacion, sFechaNacimiento, sGenero, nNumeroTelefonico, sNombreUsuario, sPassword, nEdad, sTipoUsuario, nEmergencia );



}

llenarTablaUsuarios();


function llenarTablaUsuarios(){


  var listaUsuarios = obtenerUsuarios();
  var cuerpoTabla = document.querySelector('#tblUserInfo tbody' );

  cuerpoTabla.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < listaUsuarios.length; i++) {


    var fila = cuerpoTabla.insertRow(i);

    var celdaCedula = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaPrimerNombre = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaSegundoNombre = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaPrimerApellido = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaSegundoApellido = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaNacionalidad = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaTipoIdentificacion = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaFechaNacimiento = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaEdad = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaGenero = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaNumeroTelefonico = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaTipoUsuario = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaNumeroEmergencia = fila.insertCell();
    var celdaNombreUsuario = fila.insertCell();


    celdaCedula.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][0];
    celdaPrimerNombre.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][1];
    celdaSegundoNombre.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][2];
    celdaPrimerApellido.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][3];
    celdaSegundoApellido.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][4];
    celdaNacionalidad.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][5];
    celdaTipoIdentificacion.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][6];
    celdaFechaNacimiento.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][7];
    celdaNombreUsuario.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][10];
    celdaEdad.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][12];
    celdaGenero.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][8];
    celdaNumeroTelefonico.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][9];
    celdaTipoUsuario.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][13]
    celdaNumeroEmergencia.innerHTML = listaUsuarios[i][14]

  }

}

function calcularEdad() {

  var fechaHoy = new Date();
  var fechaNacimiento = new Date(document.querySelector("#datFechaNacimiento").value);
  var edad = fechaHoy.getFullYear() - fechaNacimiento.getFullYear();
  var meses = fechaHoy.getMonth() - fechaNacimiento.getMonth();
  if (meses < 0 || (meses === 0 && fechaHoy.getDate() < fechaNacimiento.getDate())){
    edad--;
  }

}
```

I had translated the names of the gender and user type related stuff for the original question. Gender would be "genero" and user type would be "tipoUsuario"

You can ignore the "llenartablausuario" function, it's for something else

Comment: Is one of the radio buttons checked when you fire that js?

Comment: I tried it once without checking and once while checking them, neither worked. added a console.log to see the results and I got nothing, and the error was still there on the console as well.

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine if for both rbtGender and rbtUserType one option is selected. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qe2xgn9/). (open your console)

Comment: Thank you, however, I checked the fiddle and it's not returning anything on the console. I also pasted it into a codepen and it's the same thing, nothing registers on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the `document.querySelector('input[name="rbtGender"]:checked')` which is returning `null` when nothing is checked.

To avoid discrepancy you can do like -

```
sGender = document.querySelector('input[name="rbtGender"]:checked') ?  document.querySelector('input[name="rbtGender"]:checked').value : '';

sUserType = document.querySelector('input[name="rbtUserType"]:checked') ? document.querySelector('input[name="rbtUserType"]:checked').value: '';
```

Here I am checking if the checkbox contains any value if not assign `''` to `sGender` or `sUserType`.

Comment: While this seems to have solved the issue with the cannot read property value, it's still not registering any info. i will add the entire JS and HTML to the original question

Comment: @IsaacG that is the separate part :)

Comment: Yes I added a console log to the code you provided, but it would still not register anything (however, it did seem to have fixed the function, since at least it was saying that the values were in fact '' by default)                             I added the entire js and HTML to the original question to see if the problem is originating elsewhere

Comment: let me check it

Comment: Your `markup` is wrong - `</div>
 </div>
</form>` Remove two `div` tags